# How to use not greater than operator in mysql

Tags: mysql

Does mysql support !<= or !>= operator!!!
I am trying to fetch the data from the Person table where the age of a person is not greater than 30 (the age field may have null value).

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html

Comment: isn't not greater than = equal or lesser than?

Answer (score 2):

You may phrase not greater than 30 as being aged 30 or younger:

```
SELECT *
FROM Person
WHERE age <= 30;
```

By default, those records with a `null` age would not be included in the above inequality.

If you really wanted to use `NOT`, then we could try:

```
SELECT *
FROM Person
WHERE NOT age > 30;
```

But typically you will just see the appropriate inequality being used, without an explicit `NOT`.

Answer (score 1):

Not greater than can be written as `<=`

!<=  is not an operator

Comment: Yes. !<= is not an operator, but you can use `NOT COLUMN_NAME > VALUE`

Comment: My answer doesn't limit you to use any particular operator. The answer is question specific. You can use any combination of arithmetic or logical operators which fulfills your demand.

Comment: This is the correct answer for the main question.  <= is not correct because of the possibility that there could be multiple entries both greater and less than a particular value, in the case of dates for example.  This solution is true both for the question itself and the example given.

Answer (score 0):

Why not doing something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id <= 100
```

That mean the query will selecting the ID which not **GREATER THAN** 100. Or if you want to search something with specific value, you can try this :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id >= 50 AND id <= 100
```

That mean the query will search data from table which ID is **MORE THAN 50 AND NOT GREATER THAN 100**.

Hope this will help.